# How can I query my collection of tweets for a given variable (tweets with hashtags) using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, twitter, pymongo

I have a collection called "tweets" stored in my mongodb database called "test".
I connect to the db in the following manner:

```
import sys
import pymongo
import Connection from pymongo
connection = Connection()
db = connection.test
tweets = db.tweets
```

I get one document from my tweets as a list comprehension:

```
list(tweets.find())[0]
```

This shows me that the structure of the document is as follows:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('...'),
 u'contributors': None,
 u'coordinates': {u'coordinates': [-placeholder coordinate, placeholder coordinate],
  u'type': u'Point'},
 u'created_at': u'Mon Jun 24 17:53:47 +0000 2013',
 u'entities': {u'hashtags': [],
  u'symbols': [],
  u'urls': [],
  u'user_mentions': []},
 u'favorite_count': 0,
 u'favorited': False,
 u'filter_level': u'medium',
 u'geo': {u'coordinates': [40.81019674, -73.99020695], u'type': u'Point'},
 u'id': 349223842700472320L,
 u'id_str': u'349223842700472320',
 u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
 u'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
 u'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
 u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
 u'lang': u'en',
 u'place': {u'attributes': {},
  u'bounding_box': {u'coordinates': [[[placeholder coordinate, placeholder coordinate],
     [-placeholder coordinate, placeholder coordinate],
     [-placeholder coordinate, placeholder coordinate],
     [-placeholder coordinate, placeholder coordinate]]],
   u'type': u'Polygon'},
  u'country': u'placeholder country',
  u'country_code': u'example',
  u'full_name': u'name, xx',
  u'id': u'user id',
  u'name': u'name',
  u'place_type': u'city',
  u'url': u'http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/1820d77fb3f65055.json'},
 u'retweet_count': 0,
 u'retweeted': False,
 u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
 u'text': u'example text',
 u'truncated': False,
 u'user': {u'contributors_enabled': False,
  u'created_at': u'Sat Jan 22 13:42:59 +0000 2011',
  u'default_profile': False,
  u'default_profile_image': False,
  u'description': u'example description',
  u'favourites_count': 100,
  u'follow_request_sent': None,
  u'followers_count': 100,
  u'following': None,
  u'friends_count': 100,
  u'geo_enabled': True,
  u'id': placeholder_id,
  u'id_str': u'placeholder_id',
  u'is_translator': False,
  u'lang': u'en',
  u'listed_count': 0,
  u'location': u'example place',
  u'name': u'example name',
  u'notifications': None,
  u'profile_background_color': u'000000',
  u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme19/bg.gif',
  u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme19/bg.gif',
  u'profile_background_tile': False,
  u'profile_banner_url': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/241527685/1363314054',
  u'profile_image_url':    u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000038841219/8a71d0776da0c48dcc4ef6fee9f78880_normal.jpeg',
  u'profile_image_url_https':     u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000038841219/8a71d0776da0c48dcc4ef6fee9f78880_normal.jpeg',
  u'profile_link_color': u'000000',
  u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'FFFFFF',
  u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'000000',
  u'profile_text_color': u'000000',
  u'profile_use_background_image': False,
  u'protected': False,
  u'screen_name': placeholder screen_name',
  u'statuses_count': xxxx,
  u'time_zone': u'placeholder time_zone',
  u'url': None,
  u'utc_offset': -21600,
  u'verified': False}}
```

I then query for all documents with hashtags in my collection:

```
list(tweets.find({'entities.hashtags.text': {"$ne":None}}))
```

So far so good. Now, here is my problem. I would like to sort the documents in my collection by screen_name. I try:

```
users = tweets.find({'entities.hashtags.text': {"$ne":None}}, {"user.screen_name":1})
for user in users:
    print user.get["user.screen_name"]
```

but get the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/home/<ipython-input-98-ea29cbbcfe27> in <module>()
      1 for user in users:
----> 2     print user.get["screen_name"]
      3 

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, here/any idea how I can fix my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use brackets with the get method where you should use parentheses, so either access the key with `user.get('screen_name')` or `user['screen_name']`.